# Generic Object Update Function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

The `updateObject` function below takes in `oldObject` of type `T` and `newValues` of type `Partial<T>`, and then assigns any of the values present in`newValues` to `oldObject`.

My problem is that if `newValues` contains properties not present in `oldObject`, my compiler throws an error. How can I express to the compiler that I want `newValues` to be reduced to only the properties present in `oldObject`?

### Problematic code

In this code, `newValues` is of type `Partial<Point>` and `point` is of type `ThreatPoint`.

```
updateObject(point, newValues);
```

### Error Message

The error I receive says:

```
Argument of type '(point: ThreatPoint) => (ThreatPoint & Partial<ThreatPoint>) | (RoutePoint & Partial<...>)' is not assignable to parameter of type '(item: ThreatPoint) => ThreatPoint'.
  Type '(ThreatPoint & Partial<ThreatPoint>) | (RoutePoint & Partial<...>)' is not assignable to type 'ThreatPoint'.
      Types of property 'category' are incompatible.
        Type 'Category.ROUTE_POINT' is not assignable to type 'Category.THREAT'.
```

### updateObject Function

```
static updateObject = <T>(oldObject: T, newValues: Partial<T>) => {
   // Encapsulate the idea of passing a new object as the first parameter
   // to Object.assign to ensure we correctly copy data instead of mutating
   return Object.assign({}, oldObject, newValues);
};
```

### Types/Interfaces

```
export interface BasicPoint {
  category: Category;
  id: string;
  position: Coordinate;
  title: string;
  type: PointType;
}

export enum RoutePointType {
  START = 'START',
  FINISH = 'FINISH',
}

export enum ThreatPointType {
  OBSTACLE = 'OBSTACLE',
  RIVER = 'RIVER',
}

export type PointType = RoutePointType | ThreatPointType;

export enum Category {
  ROUTE_POINT = 'ROUTE_POINT',
  THREAT = 'THREAT',
}

export interface RoutePoint extends BasicPoint {
  category: Category.ROUTE_POINT;
  speed: number;
  type: RoutePointType;
}

export interface ThreatPoint extends BasicPoint {
  category: Category.THREAT;
  type: ThreatPointType;
}

export type Point = RoutePoint | ThreatPoint;
```

Comment: But your code should work. Please share the error message

Comment: By the wat, you you want to avoid mutation, `Object.assign` is not the best choice because it mutates `{}`

Comment: #captain-yossarian All of my code has been added to the post now.

Comment: There is no error tsplay.dev/m0L3Rm

Comment: @captain-yossarian That code doesn't even execute when you hit Run. It doesn't compile.

Comment: code in ts playground does get executed. It just for type checking

Answer (score 1):

I tried to manage your use case by coding something like that:

```
 static updateObject = <T extends {}, X extends T>(oldObject: T, newValues: Partial<X> ): T => {
      
      const newObjectValues = { ...newValues }

      const keysToInclude = Object.keys(oldObject);

      const newValuesKeys  = Object.keys(newValues)

      const newValuesFiltered = newValuesKeys
        .filter(key => !keysToInclude.includes(key))
        .forEach(key => delete newObjectValues[key as keyof T]);

      return Object.assign({}, oldObject, newValuesFiltered);

    };
```

Basically, I said to the typescript compiler that the function can receive an argument of `X` type which extends the property of `T`. Then, I created `newValuesFiltered` in order to obtain an object only with the keys of `T`.

Comment: This solution doesn't solve my problem. Using the code in my post, and your solution, I get this error: `Type 'Category.ROUTE_POINT' is not assignable to type 'Category.THREAT | undefined'.`